# Mule Debug port is bloked

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to debug my app but I'm having an issue with the port 6666 that's the default in the application. I check using `netstat -a` and the port is listening. Any of you have the same problem? How can I change the default port for debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the port like this: 
Debug As > Properties > Mule Debugger > Connection properties

I was having an issue like this and it was because the antivirus was blocking the port, I was able to listen but there was no connection.  try a random port like 5666 or 7777.

Comment: let me check, give me a sec :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro v^

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port by selecting the debug configurations the 3rd option Mule Deubbger and try another port like 9999. Sometimes you may have to restart Anypoint studio just to make sure the port is release from any earlier crashes process.